# Common names for shoes, which are used in the house

Tags: word-request

I was looking in the dictionary for the name of usual indoor shoes which are used by kids in the house. I found 'slippers'. The explanation of the term is in relation to the attributes. Therefore it seems inappropriate to describe flip-flops as slippers. Flip-flops are pretty common in Germany in the house during summer.

Is there a name which includes all different kind of shoes, which are worn in the house?

What are some examples for pretty common shoes used inside the house during summer or winter?

Comment: The answer to this question could be very broad and will be based on each person's opinion. I believe there are many types/ names for these kind of shoes, as there are multiple ingenious footwear in various regions, based on their weather and availability of raw materials.

Comment: Of course you're right - anyway, I guess it will be not more than 3 - 5 names to include 98 % of common models. The first 3 names which come to my mind are: slippers, sandals, flip-flops. Moreover the question remains, if there is an all-including word to describe them all.

Comment: That's why I haven't voted to [close](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) this question. This maybe broad and primarily opinion-based, which are two reason why a post maybe unfit to be posted on ELL, but I'm guessing you're looking for the most popular word for home shoes.

Comment: Okay - so home shoes would be an appropriate word. In German it is quite similar: "Hausschuhe - house shoes".

Comment: I would say [*house shoes*](https://www.wsj.com/articles/why-stylish-guys-own-house-shoes-1481829867), not "home shoes".  *House shoes* is common enough that some companies will buy it as an advertising term: https://www.google.com/search?q=house+shoes

Comment: Google Ngrams seems to confirm the popularity of *house shoes* over *home shoes*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=house+shoes%2Chome+shoes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chouse%20shoes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chome%20shoes%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect the answer to this question is based on environment and personal experience.  In my opinion, *slippers* is the best term in English for the German "home/house shoes".  A common trope in some older 1950s American TV shows was to have the "man of the family" come home from work, sit down in his favorite chair, change into his [*slippers*](https://retrowaste-jockpost.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/gallery/1950s-mens-shoes/1957-mens-shoes-slippers-01.jpg), smoke his pipe, read the newspaper, and wait for supper to be ready.

"Flip-flops" (named I think for the sound they make when you walk in them) are a variety of slipper, especially when worn inside the house.  Similar shoes meant to be worn *outside* would be called "sandals", especially if made of sturdy material.

Otherwise there is no generic term for "shoes you wear inside the house".  A slipper is a slipper, not a sneaker/trainer.

Answer (score 3):

"Slippers" is the most common term for what are sometimes more broadly known as "*house shoes*".

In the UK, "slippers" are normally made from a soft material, not at all waterproof, and so unsuitable for outdoor use. However, there are other kinds of "comfortable" shoes that individuals may choose to make their "house shoes" by wearing them exclusively indoors, even though other people may use them outdoors. Flip-flops you mentioned. "Crocs", also sometimes referred to as "clogs" or "sabos" are another. There are also "house socks", sometimes called "bed socks" which are more like thick socks than shoes but are worn around the house instead of slippers.

As these latter types of footwear I mentioned are only "house shoes" out of personal preference, you would be better using a broad term like "house shoes" or "slippers" to get your point accross.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK we would just say slippers - for me this includes flipflops

Comment: I'm from the UK, I have to disagree with this on the basis that flip-flops are worn outside and are particularly popular on the beach because they are waterproof. Kids run in and out of the water wearing them. True "slippers" are not at all waterproof.

Comment: Yeah i know what you mean, but if i wear my (home) flip flops in the house, i call them slippers, but if i wear my (holiday) flip flops out of the house, they are flip flops. I guess its more of a "what am i using them for" than a "what do normal people call them"